# Proposals to merge macroeconomics tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Does anyone have any problem with a merge-tags tag here so we can have things like `macro` and `macroeconomics` and `macro-economics` and whatever other new variants show up all linked to one tag?

Having a merge-tags tag here would be helpful for dealing with future requests (like micro, etc).

Thoughts?

Comment: If you mind me asking - what is the merge-tags feature? I've mostly been on smaller stacks that don't have that many tags.

Comment: You can request users with permission to mark tags as synonyms, combining questions under a single tag.

Comment: You wouldn't actually create a tag synonym for this use case. Simple text completion will guide uses to the right tag once you decide what that should be. Synonyms were actually designed for two completely different words that refer to the same thing. Once we leave private beta, it will be a bit more difficult to create *new* tags inadvertently, so you have to just keep nudging folks in the right direction based on what you decide the actual tag should be here.